# Why didn't Iceman answer the Slider's question?

Tags: plot-explanation, top-gun

In *Top Gun* (1986), enemy flighters shot down flighter name Hollywood so Iceman and Slider
trying to take them down:

> Iceman: I'm going after them. I'm bringing it around to the left.
>
> SLIDER: We got four on our tail! That makes six of them!
> **Who do you think is hooking in the guns range?**

Then Enemy flight starts firing them:

> Slider: He's firing! Break right!

Why didn't Iceman answer the Slider's question?

Comment: Time stamp? Video excerpt? From that bit of script it just sounds like he's suddenly got other things to think about.